# How to call native code which draw in WPF Image from C# code?

Tags: c#, wpf, interop

I have a native library (no sources available) wrapped into C# code.

The following C# declaration exists:

```
[DllImport(DRIVER_DLL_NAME, 
 CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, 
 EntryPoint = "RenderBitmap")]
private static extern int RenderBitmap(int hWnd);
```

I need to call this function from my WPF C# project.

I have a working sample code for Windows forms:

```
System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox DisplayWindow;
...
RenderBitmap(DisplayWindow.Handle.ToInt32());
```

And I have not found how to do so with WPF `System.Windows.Controls.Image` instead of `System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox` - there is no `Handle` property or something similar.

Moreover I found in ["WPF and Win32 Interoperation"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742522.aspx) the following statement:
*"When you create a WPF Window, WPF creates a top-level HWND, and uses an HwndSource to put the Window and its WPF content inside the HWND. The rest of your WPF content in the application shares that singular HWND."*.
It seems that HWND handle does not exist at all for `Image`.

How to call native code which draw in WPF Image from C# code?

Answer (score 3):

WPF Controls does not have handles like in WinForms. Only main window handle is accessible:

For instance, in main window class (or use `Application.Current.MainWindow`):

```
 var handle = (new WindowInteropHelper(this)).Handle;
 var hwnd = HwndSource.FromHwnd(handle);
```

So looks like you've to consider another approach instead of native calls.

BTW, why you need such a low level drawing functionality? I just can assume that you simply want to reuse already implemented one for WinForms. Perhaps you can achieve the same using built in WPF features.

Comment: My native library is driver of camera. And there are C# examples from vendor - wrapper around native code, but example employs WindowsForms. And my application uses WPF.

Comment: I believe I got the idea, you basically want to write your own wrappers for the WPF. Unfortunately WPF is completely an other Presentation Framework and one of the most significant differences as you already have observed - there are no HWND/Window for each control as in WinForms

Comment: @sergdev - The solution would be to place a System.Controls.Image within a Win32 Form and place the form within a Window.  An alternative to this solution is contact the vendor and ask for support.

Comment: @sll I just need to make calls to native library, I am not writing  general wrapper for WPF. It seems that I will have to implement by hands some already existing native functionality in C# :(

Comment: @Ramhound it should work but looks strange :) Good idea to contact vendor

Comment: @sergdev - If you want another alernative you would have to provide us the name of library in question.  It seems odd they would be using handles, that an odd way of returning an image, you might not even need a handle per say.